# MySQL Query - order by date and group fields inside date range

Tags: mysql

I want to order the following query by date and by code ASC, in the same day:
Ex. all tickets made in certain date (ordered by datetime) and in the same day ordered by code.

I've tried with group by but it doesn't work.

Here is my query;

```
SELECT 
      tck_NRicevuta as ticket,
      tck_dataOUT AS date_out,
      tck_ID_tariffa AS code,
      park_ticket.tck_importo AS ToTal 
  FROM
      park_ticket 
 WHERE
      tck_flaguscita =  'U'
ORDER BY
      date_out, code
```

[Query result: wrong!!- I'd want ordered by datetime and then by code in the same day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLa8N.jpg)

Comment: Try using ORDER BY DATE(date_out), code

Answer (score 0):

You can order results by date only by using `date()` on `date_out`

```
SELECT tck_NRicevuta as ticket,
    tck_dataOUT AS date_out,
    tck_ID_tariffa AS code,
    park_ticket.tck_importo AS ToTal 
FROM park_ticket 
WHERE tck_flaguscita =  'U' 
ORDER BY date(date_out),code
```